# Junit VerificationModeFactory.times() vs mockito.times()

Tags: junit, mocking, verify

What is the difference between VerificationModeFactory.times() and mockito.times()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I thought it would be faster to ask rather than go check by myself :) I was lazy and wrong so I did the check by myself and here is the answer. It is the same thing, **Mockito.Times()** is internally calling the **VerificationModeFactory.times()**

From **Mockito.class**

```
/**
 * Allows verifying exact number of invocations. E.g:
 * <pre>
 *   verify(mock, times(2)).someMethod("some arg");
 * </pre>
 * 
 * See examples in javadoc for {@link Mockito} class
 * 
 * @param wantedNumberOfInvocations wanted number of invocations 
 * 
 * @return verification mode
 */
public static VerificationMode times(int wantedNumberOfInvocations) {
    return VerificationModeFactory.times(wantedNumberOfInvocations);
}
```